# Navigation buttons on top of ModalBottomSheet

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I use `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta02` for `ModalBottomSheet`. But on some devices with navigation buttons i have an issue:

```
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
        windowInsets = WindowInsets.Companion.navigationBars
    ) {
        Column {
            itemList.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I try to find some solutions like this - [How to prevent ModalBottomSheet from overlapping with the system buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245357/how-to-prevent-modalbottomsheet-from-overlapping-with-the-system-buttons). Yes, indeed, from a certain version we can set up `windowInsets` for ModalBottomSheet. By default: `windowInsets: WindowInsets = BottomSheetDefaults.windowInsets,`

But neither the default nor the others I tried (`windowInsets = WindowInsets.Companion.navigationBars`, `windowInsets = WindowInsets.Companion.ime`) solved my problem. Are there any other options to prevent the buttons from overlapping my ModalBottomSheet?

Comment: Like temporary solutions i found the next: `Spacer(Modifier.navigationBarsPadding())`